# Apache camel,RabbitMQ how to send messages/objects

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, rabbitmq

I hope someone can provide some help on this matter.

I am using camel rabbitmq and for testing purpose I am trying to send a message to the queue, which I'm trying to display in rabbitmq interface and then also read it back.

However I can't get this working.

What I believe works is that I created, in the exchange tab of rabbitmq management interface, a new exchange. 
In my java code I send the message to that exchange. When the code is executed, I can see a spike in the web interface showing that something has been received but I can't see what has been received. 
When I try to read, I can't read and get the following errror: 
< in route: Route(route2)[[From[rabbitmq://192.168.59.103:5672/rt... because of Route route2 has no output processors. You need to add outputs to the route such as to("log:foo").

Can someone provide me a practical example on how to send a message,see it in the web interace and also read it? any tutorial showing this process will be also appreciated.

Thank you

=================
SECOND PART

The error I'm getting now is the following:

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; reason: {#method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - cannot redeclare exchange 'rhSearchExchange' in vhost '/' with different type, durable, internal or autodelete value, class-id=40, method-id=10), null, ""}
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:343)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:216)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
    ... 47 more
```

I have the following settings:

I get this error, I believe I’m doing something wrong with the URI and I have to define some extra parameters that I’m missing
My exchange is of direct type
My queue is of durable type 
And my uri is : 
rabbitmq://192.168.59.105:5672/rhSearchExchange?username=guest&password=guest&routingKey=rhSearchQueue

any input on this?

Thanks

Comment: any advice on this ?

Comment: I've been looking for a similar tutorial... I can publish messages to the exchange but I can't consume them from camel. 

However, for your error, I think the problem is you aren't routing the message anywhere. For example, I believe your configuration is `from("rabbitmq:localhost...");` but it should be `from("rabbitmq:localhost:...").to("foo:bar")`

`foo:bar` could be something like `mock:result`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand that I have to use "to" to stream it/save it somewhere. I have updated my thread to show the error that I'm getting now. If anyone has anyone advice on how to solve this.

Comment: PLEASE READ FROM THE SECOND PART AS THAT IS THE ERROR I'M GETTING NOW

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I was able to figure this out yesterday, I had the same (or at least similar) problems you were having.

The options you have in the RabbitMQ URI must exactly match the options that your exchange was created with. For example, in my configuration, I had an exchange called `tasks` that was a direct type, was durable, and was not configured to autodelete. Note that the default value for the autodelete option in the rabbitmq camel component is `true`. Additionally, I wanted to get the messages with the routing key `camel`. That means my rabbitmq URI needed to look like:

```
rabbitmq:localhost:5672/tasks?username=guest&password=guest&autoDelete=false&routingKey=camel
```

Additionally, I wanted to read from an existing queue, called `task_queue` rather than have the rabbitmq camel component declare it's own queue. Therefore, I also needed to add an additional query parameter, so my rabbitmq URI was

```
rabbitmq:localhost:5672/tasks?username=guest&password=guest&autoDelete=false&routingKey=camel&queue=task_queue
```

This configuration worked for me. Below, I added some Java code snippets from the code that configures the exchange and queue and sends a message, and my Camel Route configuration.

### Exchange and Queue configuration:

```
rabbitConnFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
rabbitConnFactory.setHost("localhost");
final Connection conn = rabbitConnFactory.newConnection();
final Channel channel = conn.createChannel();

// declare a direct, durable, non autodelete exchange named 'tasks'    
channel.exchangeDeclare("tasks", "direct", true); 
// declare a durable, non exclusive, non autodelete queue named 'task_queue'
channel.queueDeclare("task_queue", true, false, false, null); 
// bind 'task_queue' to the 'tasks' exchange with the routing key 'camel'
channel.queueBind("task_queue", "tasks", "camel");
```

### Sending a message:

```
channel.basicPublish("tasks", "camel", MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_TEXT_PLAIN, "hello, world!".getBytes());
```

### Camel Route:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("rabbitmq:localhost:5672/tasks?username=guest&password=guest&autoDelete=false&routingKey=camel&queue=task_queue")
        .to("mock:result");
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot llawj, it worked. I added autoDelete=false and also the name of the queue as well as the routingkey which was already there before. So basically it was a matter of getting the right uri. One problem that I'm having is that when it reads the queue, it reads all the messages in it? I tried to set prefetchEnabled=true and prefetchCount=1 in the uri but that throughs an error. Any advice on how to pull only one message? Thank you

Comment: I'm not really sure, to be honest. I'm just getting started with Camel / RabbitMQ, and I haven't needed to limit the number of messages I'm reading.

Comment: I'll check if I can find a way to do it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looks like as of Camel 2.14 there is no need to perform manual exchange, queue and binding declaration. Please, take a look at http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html There is 'declare' option, that is true by default

Comment: @cpu2007 what is the error that you see? have you tried autoAck=false in addition to prefetchCount=1? This way broker won't give more messages until you send an ack for the one you're processing

Answer (score 5):

Because this it the top hit on Google for rabbitmq/camel integration I feel the need to add a bit more to the subject.  The lack of *simple* camel examples is astonishing to me.

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ConsumerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.Endpoint;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CamelTests {
    CamelContext context;
    ProducerTemplate producer;
    ConsumerTemplate consumer;
    Endpoint endpoint;

    @Test
    public void camelRabbitMq() throws Exception {
        context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        context.start();

        endpoint = context.getEndpoint("rabbitmq://192.168.56.11:5672/tasks?username=benchmark&password=benchmark&autoDelete=false&routingKey=camel&queue=task_queue");

        producer = context.createProducerTemplate();

        producer.setDefaultEndpoint(endpoint);
        producer.sendBody("one");
        producer.sendBody("two");
        producer.sendBody("three");
        producer.sendBody("four");
        producer.sendBody("done");

        consumer = context.createConsumerTemplate();
        String body = null;
        while (!"done".equals(body)) {
            Exchange receive = consumer.receive(endpoint);
            body = receive.getIn().getBody(String.class);
            System.out.println(body);
        }

        context.stop();

    }

}
```

Comment: From _Producer-/ConsumerTemplates'_ JavaDoc:„**Important:** Make sure to call `org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate.stop()` | `ConsumerTemplate.stop()` when you are done using the template, to clean up any resources.“